# Python - Finding specific string [At least 2 words]

Tags: python, arrays, loops, spacing

Another question from total Python newbie.

I have an array, user can input 5 different words/sentences, after user enters those 5, user enters one of the 5 texts again and program removes this string from array, than user adds another string and it appends directly to the Index = 0.

But the problem begins when i want to run over this array and find if any of the strings in the array have at least 2 words.

```
Text = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    Text.append(input('Enter the text: '))

    print (Text)
for i in range(0, 1):
    Text.remove(input('Enter one of the texts you entered before: '))
    print (Text)

for i in range(0, 1):
    Text.insert(0,input('Enter Some Text: '))
    print (Text)

for s in Text:
    if s.isspace():
        print(Text[s])
```

Output :

> ```
> Enter the text: A
> ['A']
> Enter the text: B
> ['A', 'B']
> Enter the text: C D
> ['A', 'B', 'C D']
> Enter the text: E
> ['A', 'B', 'C D', 'E']
> Enter the text: F
> ['A', 'B', 'C D', 'E', 'F']
> Enter one of the texts you entered before: F
> ['A', 'B', 'C D', 'E']
> Enter Some Text: G
> ['G', 'A', 'B', 'C D', 'E']
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

So, my code doesn't do anything, i need to somehow find if any of the strings have at least 2 words and print all of those words.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a single input value is multiple words?  If so, the function split() takes a string and returns a list of the strings without white spaces.  Example: my_string = "hello world".split() then my_string = ["hello", "world"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, my code doesn't do anything, i need to somehow find if any of the
>   strings have at least 2 words and print all of those words.

Perhaps loop through the list and split each string. Then determine if the resulting sum is greater than 1:

```
text_list = ['G', 'A', 'B', 'C D', 'E']

for i in range(len(text_list)):
    if len(text_list[i].split(' ')) > 1:
        print(text_list[i])
```

Using list comprehension:

```
x = [w for w in text_list if len(w.split(' ')) > 1]
print(x)
```

Comment: YEAH, thank you very much, now it works and now i understood how it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
for s in Text:
if s.isspace():
    print(Text[s])
```

In the code above, s is the full string for example in your example s could be 'C D' and this string is not a space.

To check if s has two or more words you can use .split(' ') but before that you have to .strip() your string to delete spaces from borders.

```
s = 'Hello World '
print(s.strip().split(' '))
>>> ['Hello', 'World']
```

In the example above, s has two spaces, so strip delete the last space because is a border space and then split gives you a list of string that are separate by spaces.

So the solution to your problem could be

```
for s in Text:
    if len(s.strip().split(' ')) > 1:
        print(s.strip().split(' '))
```